# Unit test in Swift for beginner in TDD

Tags: ios, swift, tdd, xctest

I'm going to take serious TDD and tests in my code. But I have doubts if using XCTest is best way to start with TDD.

- Are serious devteams using it or another? Maybe there are better
  frameworks and using XCTest is waste of time.
- Is 90% code cover with test realy needed or only crucial
  parts?

Comment: can you help me with thes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534903/performance-testing-of-for-loop-in-swift-using-tdd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with XCTest, a lot of teams us it (mine included). There are other testing frameworks that help with asynchronous tests, have different syntax such as BDD style syntax, but you will be fine with XCTest initially.

Don't worry about code coverage in the beginning. It takes time to get into the habit of writing tests, and some tests for UI code are really hard to write, so I would just focus on improving coverage week by week.

Comment: +1 ,can you help me with these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534903/performance-testing-of-for-loop-in-swift-using-tdd