# Performance testing in Swift using TDD

Tags: ios, swift, testing, tdd, performance-testing

Just learning `Test Driven Development` in `Swift`.I created a class that is subclass of `XCTestCase`  in the "ProjectNameTests" group.

```
    class BasicFunctionTest: XCTestCase {

        var values : [Int]?
        override func setUp() {
            super.setUp()
            // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

        }

        override func tearDown() {
            // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
            super.tearDown()
        }

        func testExample() {
            // This is an example of a functional test case.
            XCTAssert(true, "Pass")
        }

        func testPerformanceExample() {
            // This is an example of a performance test case.
            self.measureBlock() {
                // Put the code you want to measure the time of here.
                for i in 1...100000{

                    println("ok i need to know the time for execution")


                }
            }
        }
}
```

I want to perform performance testing of these method

```
func testPerformanceExample() {
    // This is an example of a performance test case.
    self.measureBlock() {
        // Put the code you want to measure the time of here.
        for i in 1...100000{

            println("ok i need to know the time for execution")


        }
    }
}
```

and want to find out the time for execution of the `for` loop.I run the project on going to Product -> Perform Action - > Test Without Building.

I can see the execution time as 3.50 sec but when i try to set the baseline clicking on the Stroke Area as below image:

[image]

I get warning as  as

> Would you like to update the baseline values for all tests on all
>   devices? You'll have a chance to review the changes the next time you
>   commit to source control.

Now when i click on Update the error is as below:

[image]

How can i set Baseline of the time for my specific method as [Here](http://samuelmullen.com/2014/10/performance_testing_in_swift/)

Here is my test project :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzk4QVQhnqKmUzYyclp6ZnJvekE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check whether BasicFunctionTest file Target membership includes your test target. You should be able to check this by selecting the file and navigating to File Inspector (target membership).

Comment: thanks for your response....i double checked it.....and its done...i have uploaded my project..please see my question

Comment: strange, I just tried the same step and was able to update the baseline.

Comment: did you just tried in the demo project that i have created??which xcode version are you using?

Comment: Yes the same UnitTesting project, Xcode version is 6.4

Comment: i just downloaded xcode 6.4 and tested ..well everything is fine..my bad was using xcode 6.3 although having few bugs in it :) any thanks