# How to do App performance testing with XCode 7 or 8 (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, performance, performance-testing, xcode8

I can see Xcode supports performance testing. I tried to find some resources / links on explaining how can i use xcode for testing performance on my app.

I ended with some Objective C tests but I believe we can use swift.

Can anyone please share any useful link / reference on writing performance test with Swift.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance testing in Swift using TDD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534903/performance-testing-in-swift-using-tdd)

Comment: Thanks @Anish웃 Probably you are right but My question was on getting complete performance testing knowledge with iOS app. like is there any book? website ? tutorials?